# Another way to use SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable r)?

Tags: java, swing, event-dispatch-thread

All my sample programs create a big `JFrame` which contains all the code for its components, instead of creating separate classes for components and then adding these components to the big `JFrame`. This big `JFrame` is run or displayed by instantiating it inside an anonymous `Runnable` as shown below.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {  
    // Create the frame on the event dispatching thread.  
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {  
        public void run() {  
            new StopWatch();  // Or any other JFrame
        }  
    });  
}
```

Class `StopWatch` implements `ActionListener`. Would it make any difference if I make it class `StopWatch` implements `ActionListener`, `Runnable` and then pass it as a runnable to the `invokeLater` method ? Is there is any other way of doing what the above code does ?

Comment: The bottom line is that you want to create and run your GUI's on the Swing event thread, the EDT. What is wrong with the way you've posted above? Why try to change it? As an aside, you really shouldn't have your GUI/view code implement listener interfaces or Runnable interfaces since that's asking the class to do too much and violates the high cohesion/low coupling rule.

Comment: There's no particular reason why you couldn't (implement `Runnable`) and pass it to `SwingWorker.invokeLater` other the then fact you've now introduced/exposed the `run` method for no good reason, which could lead to some one passing to a `Thread`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - I wanted to know if there would be any problems or advantages in making the JFrame a Runnable as well.

Comment: @MadProgrammer - How do you highlight those classes JFrame and all ? I could do it myself next time and save you all the trouble :)

Comment: Again, it makes for a low cohesive class, one with too many responsibilities, which is asking for trouble. While yes it can be done, it really shouldn't I think.

Comment: @SuperStar In the question editor, you can highlight the text and click the "{}" button, which will place the text in ` ` quotes

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - Should I make separate classes for each of the major components of the Big JFrame and then run each of these components using invokeLater() or just add these components to big JFrame and run the JFrame inside the invokeLater() ?

Comment: 1) should you make separate classes for major components -- yes. 2) and then run each of these... -- this doesn't make sense. The GUI is created in the Runnable as you note above, and the GUI creation code will create instances of the classes described above, but since this creation code is already running on the event thread, nothing more need be done.